# external variable is not available to thread until blocking call is made...

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++-2010, win32gui

I have two code files, one contains my `WinMain()` function, and all functions related to my main dialog window. The other contains a thread callback and variable functions related to my program. I have defined `HWND hWnd = NULL` as a global variable in MainDlg.cpp and defined `extern HWND hWnd` in Other.cpp (which contains the thread callback). The thread is created when the `WM_INITDIALOG` message is sent to the window. Inside the thread callback, the `hWnd` variable is null until long operation is performed, then after that it becomes available.

**MainDlg.cpp**

```
HWND hWnd = NULL;
HANDLE hListenThread = NULL;

DWORD WINAPI ListenThread( LPVOID lpvParam );

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
    /* ... */
    if( NULL == (hWnd=CreateDialog( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAINDLG), NULL, (DLGPROC)WndProc)) )
    {
        MessageBox( NULL, "Error creating the main dialog!", NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR );
        return -1;
    }

    MSG msg;
    while( GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0) && IsWindow(hWnd) )
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            DWORD dwListenThreadId = NULL;
            /* referencing hWnd here works fine... */
            /* ... */
            hListenThread = CreateThread(
                NULL,
                0,
                ListenThread,
                hWndDlg,
                0,
                &dwListenThreadId);
            /* ... */
        } break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Other.cpp**

```
extern HWND hWnd;
DWORD WINAPI ListenThread( LPVOID lpvParam )
{

    if( hWnd == NULL )
        MessageBox( NULL, "hWnd == NULL", NULL, MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL );

    if( hWnd != NULL )
        MessageBox( NULL, "hWnd != NULL", NULL, MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL );

    return 0;
}
```

Both Message Boxes in the `ListenThread` callback are displayed when the application is launched. Can someone please tell me why this is happening? **Is there something I can do to fix this besides doing `while( hWnd == NULL );` at the beginning of my `ListenThread` ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WM_INITDIALOG` message occurs **before** `CreateDialog` returns and `hWnd` isn't set until `CreateDialog` returns.  So the thread starts running before CreateDialog returns and sets the global `hWnd` variable.

So you could fix this by moving your thread creation from the `WM_INITDIALOG` message to just after the return of `CreateDialog`.

But you don't need to do that because you code doesn't required the global `hWnd` variable.  You are already passing your dialogs window handle as the parameter to the thread start procedure.  So just cast the lpvParam to an `HWND` and use that.  That will let you get rid of your global variable, which is bad practice to use.

**Other.cpp**

```
DWORD WINAPI ListenThread( LPVOID lpvParam )
{
    HWND hWnd= (HWND)lpvParam;

    if( hWnd == NULL )
        MessageBox( NULL, "hWnd == NULL", NULL, MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL );

    if( hWnd != NULL )
        MessageBox( NULL, "hWnd != NULL", NULL, MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I was driving home from work, I realized that's what it was. Passing `hWndDlg` to the thread's `lpvParam` parameter actually should not have been in this question. That was from early on in the development of the code, before I discovered I needed more `extern` variables and changed it to `extern`. I just forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The `WM_INITDIALOG` message is issued to `WndProc()` from inside of `CreateDialog()` itself, not by `DispatchMessage()`. This is stated as much in the `CreateDialog()` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645434.aspx). Your `hWnd` variable is not assigned until after `CreateDialog()` exits.  If your thread starts running before `CreateDialog()` exits (depending on task scheduling, that is not a guarantee), your first `MessageBox()` gets called.  While the `MessageBox()` is running, `CreateDialog()` has time to exit and assign the variable, which is why the second `MessageBox()` gets called after you dismiss the first `MessageBox()`.

You don't need to use the `hWnd` variable in your thread at all.  You are passing the dialog `HWND` to the `lpParameter` parameter of `CreateThread()`, so it will appear in the `lpvParam` parameter of `ListenThread()`, eg:

```
DWORD WINAPI ListenThread( LPVOID lpvParam )  
{  
    HWND hWnd = (HWND) lpvParam;  
    ...
    return 0;  
}
```